# Likelihood for Discrepancy in GETDATE() Values Within UPDATE Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, datetime

As the title alludes to I am wondering if it is possible or if you have experienced an issue with differing GETDATE() results within the same UPDATE statement.

I have a stored procedure which updates a record that contains two DateTime columns, there is also a CASE statement therein, generally the update is as follows:

```
 UPDATE A
        SET Status = dbo.func('P')
           ,Time1 = GETDATE()
           ,Time2 = ISNULL(A.Time2, GETDATE())
           ,ModifiedOn = GETDATE()
        FROM dbo.Table A
        WHERE A.ID = @ID
        AND A.RowID = @RowID;
```

I am seeing the Time2 value be slightly later, but always in an increment of 3 or 4. This seems to be due SQL server rounding the datetime to the nearest 0.000, 0.003, 0.007 by design [Stack Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327065/why-does-conversion-from-datetime-to-datetime2-appear-to-change-value).

I am thinking this discrepancy is being caused by a slight delay between the two GETDATE() calls and that the delay generally accounts for one 'tick' since I only ever see the difference between Time2 - Time1 = {-.003, -.004}.

Is it possible for the aforementioned query to return two distinct GETDATE() results?

Answer (score 11):

`GETDATE` is one of the intrinsics considered to be a runtime constant. It is evaluated once at statement startup and then returns the same cached value for every row.

Each instance of a runtime constant is cached separately. Each will therefore return the same value every time it is evaluated, but the initially cached values may vary by a small amount.

You have three such instances.

To be clear: In your example, the value stored in *Time1* will be the same in every row. The value stored in *Time2* will be the same in every row. The value stored in *ModifiedOn* will be the same in every row. The values in *Time1*, *Time2*, and *ModifiedOn* may differ.

If you want the values to always be the same, the safest way is to assign the value of `GETDATE` to a variable and use the variable in the target statement instead:

```
DECLARE 
    @Now datetime = GETDATE();

UPDATE A
SET [Status] = dbo.func('P'),
    Time1 = @Now,
    Time2 = ISNULL(A.Time2, @Now),
    ModifiedOn = @Now
FROM dbo.[Table] AS A
WHERE
    A.ID = @ID
    AND A.RowID = @RowID;
```